# Getting line numbers in footnotes with bigfoot / manyfoot

Tags: footnotes, line-numbering, bigfoot

I am using the `bigfoot` package for footnotes, and trying to use `lineno` / `fnlineno` for line numbers. I haven't been able to get them to work together.

The [documentation for fnlineno](http://mirrors.rit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/lineno/fnlineno.pdf) obliquely suggests that it should work with bigfoot:

> Nothing is known about compatibility with packages (other than manyfoot and bigfoot) providing footnote features beyond standard LaTeX.

(I presume that "known" means it works, not that it's known not to work.)

Here is a minimal (non)working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}[alph]

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{fnlineno}
\modulolinenumbers[5]

\begin{document}
\linenumbers

The main text of the page, 
and a footnote.\footnoteA{Footnotes of the first kind. \lipsum[1]} \lipsum[1]
\begin{verse}
Verse line 1 \\
Verse line 2 \\
Verse line 3 \\
Verse line 4
\end{verse}
Some more text 
and a footnote.\footnoteB{Footnotes of the second kind. \lipsum[1]} \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

This produces the following output, without line numbers in the footnotes:

[image: Example with bigfoot and lineno and fnlineno -- no line numbers in footnotes]

This is an example of the desired output (note that the column of line numbers extends into the footnotes as well):

[image: A page with line numbers continuing into the footnotes]

Could someone figure it out, or are there alternatives, for either the line-numbering functionality or the footnotes functionality? The reason for using `bigfoot` is that I have three kinds of footnote (footnote blocks FootnoteA, FootnoteB, and FootnoteC). I want the line numbers to appear across all three footnote blocks.

Any help will be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: %PLEASE COMPILE USING XELATEX

Comment: %PL USE XELATEX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{perpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\begin{document}
{\huge work}
\linenumbers
\begin{center}
\par verse\par
v\par
v\par
v\par
\end{center}
I WANT NUMBERING TO BE CONTINUOUS THROUGH THE PAGE (TEXT plus FN BLCKS)
\FootnoteA{ }{
\normalsize
1ST FN BLOCK  LINE NUMBERS CONTINUED FROM THE END OF THE TEXT ABOVE.
\lipsum{1}
}
\FootnoteB{ }{
\normalsize
2ND FN BLOCK  LINE NUMBERS CONTINUED FROM THE END OF THE FIRST FOOTNOTE BLOCK
}
\end{document}

Comment: Based on communication with the OP (@ShrivathsaB), I have edited the question to be more informative.